# Which collection type is best to create poco classes in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

We have following Two tables, which collection type is the  best for this situation , and how do we choose in other scenarios.

```
public class Employee{
public int Id {get;Set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
}
public class Comapany{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public virtual ICollection<Employee>employees{get;set;} or
public virtual list<Employee>employees{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The general recommendation is to use the least specific type/interface, i.e. `ICollection<T>`, unless you want to enforce specific requirements.

The reason is that you have the freedom to use specific types appropriate to any situation. Let me give an example.

Suppose you have a method by which `Employee`s are added to a new `Company` but you want to guarantee that these employees will be unique by name. If `Company.Employees` is an `ICollection<T>` you can now use a `HashSet<Employee>` that you initialize by the [constructor taking an `IEqualityComparer<Employee>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) comparing `Employee`s by name, and assign it to `Company.Employees`.

For other sceneario's you may want to use `List<Employee>` because `AddRange` comes in handy.

The Visual Studio tools for reverse-engineering code-first from database create POCO classes that initialize their collections by `HashSet`s, because they provide high-performance set operations.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation it doesn't matter, EF will use `List<T>` in place on `ICollection<T>` by default. Collection type doesn't affect LINQ queries too. In other situations, you should choose what collection is more suited for your application logic. Common choices are `List<T>` and `HashSet<T>`.